# How can I remote control an https site in google chrome through Selenium RC

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, certificate

I have a simple test that connects to an internal portal.  I have selenium RC connecting to several browsers on a VM (IE7, FF 4, Opera, Chrome).  When I send my test to FF or IE the test runs fine, when I send it to Chrome, I am getting a certificate error:

The site's security certificate is not trusted!
You attempted to reach portal.xxx.com, but the server presented a certificate issued by an entity that is not trusted by your computer's

I have used certmgr.msc to add *.xxx.com certificate to windows trusted list.  I also have examined the certification chain.

*.xxx.com is certified by Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority, which is listed in my Intermediate Certification Authorities.

Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority is certified by Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority, which is listed in my Trusted Root Certification Authorites

Excellent suggestion by Ross.  To implement I have made the following change in my launch of the remote control:

```
ant -Denvironment="Chrome on %OS_Name%" -DseleniumArgs="-trustAllSSLCertificates" -Dhost="%username%.xxxxxlab.yyyyy.com" -DhubURL="http://segrid.xxxxxlab.yyyyy.com:4444" -Dport=5558 launch-remote-control
```

Is that correct?  If so, it is not solving my problem

Comment: Dunno about the "-DSeleniumArgs" bit, that depends on what your Ant script does with it.  But if it makes it onto the "selenium-server.jar" command as "-trustAllSSLCertificates", then yes, that ought to have helped.

Comment: I had a couple small errors in the command.  Which I have changed and all is working.  Specifically I changed -DSeleniumArgs="trust... to -DseleniumArgs="-trust...  changed the "S" to lower case and added a "-".  It is working now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selenium RC generates a new browser profile every time it starts a browser.  This sounds like a problem with getting your SSL-configuration change into that new profile.

RC's Firefox support has a way for you to supply a starter-set of profile content, which RC uses instead of its baked-in starter-set.  It doesn't appear that the Chrome support has anything similar.  The place to add it would probably be in /server-coreless/src/main/java/org/openqa/selenium/server/browserlaunchers/GoogleChromeLauncher.java, at least in the 1.0.x source.

It appears that Selenium 2.0b3 might work for you.  Svn #9567 (2010-09-01) added a "-trustAllSSLCertificates" option to tell Chrome to ignore certificate errors.